# Trunk POMs version are not updated after the release process

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I'm facing some problems regarding the release process using maven. Here is my situation:

I'm working on project with poms version is ***5.13.0-SNAPSHOT***. after the work was done i made a new release.
    mvn release:prepare -Darguments=-Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dusername=xxxxxxx -Dpassword=xxxx

the process ask me as usual about the DEV version, Tag name and version, release version :

```
- What is the release version for "parent-project"? (com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx:parent-project) 5.13.0: 
- What is SCM release tag or label for "parent-project"? (com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:parent-project) parent-project-5.13.0: : project-tag-5.13.0
- What is the new development version for "parent-project"? (com.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx:parent-project) 5.13.1-SNAPSHOT: : 5.14.0-SNAPSHOT
```

every thing seems to be perfect until the process is stooped due to some space issue inside the server maven repository. As first action i was forced to delete some space in order the build take place again.

after that i made `mvn release:prepare -Darguments=-Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dusername=xxxxxxx -Dpassword=xxxx` 
but this time there is no questions about the version [tag, DEV, Release] . the build was success the tag was created ***tag.5.13.0*** but my trunk [ project inside my eclipse ] was not updated [i.e the version was ***5.13.0-Snapshot as the first time instead of 5.14.0.Snapshot***]. the pom modification was only on the server side were the project was.

i should mentioned that usually after the process is done i should have two commit inside in the history of my project . the first is about tag creation , the second is about update poms version on DEV environment [trunk] . but there was no one of them this time.

as first step i made `mvn release:clean` then i repeat the process.
but this time the prompt question was different :

```
 - What is the release version for "parent-project"? (com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx:parent-project) 5.14.0: [instead of 5.13.0]
    - What is SCM release tag or label for "parent-project"? (com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:parent-project) parent-project-5.14.0: : [instead of 5.13.0]
    - What is the new development version for "parent-project"? (com.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx:parent-project) 5.14.0-SNAPSHOT: :  [instead of 5.13.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

. it seems the process was done only on sever side, that why i'cant get any update when i syhnchronise my project trunk under the eclipse.

my question is haw can i repeat this process as the first time [ poms version should be 5.13.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 5.14.0-SNAPSHOT ]
should i update all poms version inside my project to be 5.13.0-SNAPSHOT manually and then call again the process to simulate as the first time ?

Comment: Are you really using `-Snapshot` ? and *not* `-SNAPSHOT` ?

Comment: yes -SNAPSHOT, I'm writing -Snapshot here just for explanation

Comment: If something goes wrong during `release:..` you should use `release:rollback`....Furthermore you have to remove the created tag and than you need to delete the release versions from your repository manager if you use one and finally you can restart....

Comment: about release rollback i can't make this as to rollback a release, the following requirement must be met: You haven't run release:clean on the project.
Now about the second option.this is my question so i do need to delete the created tag and then rollback manually the pom version to the previous one , and then recall the process ?

Comment: Yes...for the pom version i would suggest to make a reverse merge  (svn) or revert the commit (in git) (depending on your version control) ....

Comment: thanks for your cooperation